# Tricky Lazy Loading Question

Tags: html, lazy-loading

Greetings Overflowers,

- A result-set grid will be viewing snaps from HTML pages.
- Snaps need to reserve original page layout including any tables, images...
- Users will scroll through a snap to fully read a snapped page
- Snaps can view varying-size windows anywhere in the HTML pages

**Question:** can lazy loading be implemented such that only viewed windows is loaded without losing the interactivity (e.g. hyperlinks) of snapped HTML pages ? If HTML pages cannot be tailored dynamically and lazy loaded this way, any interactive document format (e.g. PDF, Flash) is welcomed.

**Update:** Sorry for the confusion. Snaps are not images, they are random viewports anywhere from the HTML pages. In images it is simple, we can load only the portion we need to view. In HTML this is difficult, except when the portion is actually a whole viewable HTML tag element and it fits the needed portion. iframes would only facilitate the window to view the snaps onto, but I do not want to load the whole HTML pages because they are big, but only the needed snaps. The problem snaps can be somewhere in the middle of pages layout divisions where each division is very big. Therefore, fixing the layout size and lazy load their content later on alone would not help. I think layout transformations are necessary but very difficult. I wish I can take a picture of the full HTML pages and take whereever portion I need to view and this image portion keep interactive :)

Thanks !

Comment: You mean, you want to create snapshots of web sites that retain their functionality? While not impossible, that sounds like a task for a 50+ people team of specialists at Google. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Can you explain what you are asking for that's over and above what an IFRAME does?

Comment: @Reinderien: yes, thank you. It is not about loading selective layout elements but loading selective content of these elements since they are in view only partially.

Comment: @Reindeerien @Geeko - without loading the whole DOM you can't say what goes where on the page as later elements could change the entire layout (e.g. table column widths, etc.).  Javascript will further complicate matters as you'll need to allow it to run too on many modern web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript with XMLHttpRequest (XHR) to fetch content asynchronously and place that text on the page (i.e. lazily loading content). I am not familiar with some of the terms that you are using (e.g. what a "snap" is), but if your layout specifies sizes (instead of relying on content, for example, to set the size of a table column), then this lazy loading can be done without re-rendering the layout.

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret it - you have some fixed-size "viewport" div with scrollbars. You have Javascript that monitors the scrolling events of the viewport. You have to (somehow) have some rough idea of what content elements go where on the inner page. If a section is scrolled into view that has not been loaded, then send for it using AJAX. I think the trickiest part of this endeavour would be establishing the rough idea of what content elements go where without completely loading the content page, but perhaps you already have some assumptions you can make about the content.

Edit:

> I do not want to load the whole HTML pages because they are big

This seems to indicate that you in fact *do* have some assumptions about the pages you're working with. How are the pages "big"? Do they have massive tables, massive images, a large number of images, flash content, javascript content...? You might have better success with loading all of the DOM that isn't of a certain tag type, and then selectively loading the rest.

Comment: I cannot predict before hand the structure of the HTML pages. How would you deal with an element that is way bigger in size than the viewport ? I do not want to load it all which is impossible in HTML !

Comment: It is possible to load that element, but only selectively load its children that are visible (and not those that are currently hidden).

Comment: This is assuming it has children, but if not and it is full of text (which is probably the case in my app) then I will need to load the whole text which is very big. I wish there is a way !

Comment: Thank you all for your contribution. Yes "they have massive tables, massive images, a large number of images, flash content, javascript content..." but not always. Let say a textual HTML element is on view now, would you suggest to load the this element even if it has very large text (>1M) ?

Comment: It's extremely rare that you would find a single element containing over 1MB of text; text is usually broken up into divs. Even if it was 1MB of text, that wouldn't take too long to render, unless you're designing for some sort of embedded system. I'm starting to smell premature optimization here. Have you implemented the system without all of this complicated selective rendering yet and observed that it's unusably slow?

Comment: Actually it is not human readable text. It is some sort of geo-like data (earth layers) and unfortunately it is common in this app. I am working on testing it now. Do you think HTML is just not the answer ?

Comment: It depends. Can you post a link to a sample of the HTML data?